# Displaying jsp page on same location using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to display jsp page  on same location  using javascript.I tried below ways,but no luck:

```
location.href='./start.do';
self.location.href='./start.do';
```

chaitu

Comment: What do you mean be "on same location"?

Comment: @ Ash Burlaczenko: same location means ,where we call javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean: `window.location.assign('start.do');`

Otherwise I'm not clear on what the question is asking. I'm assuming you mean that you want to load a JSP page whose location is in the same folder as the current page (in which case, no need to use `./` in the location).

Comment: my action not submitted.I tried this,window.location.assign('start.do'):

Comment: @user569125 I think we'll need to see a bit more code then to see why it's not working. We have no frame of reference for where you're using the function (and it works perfectly fine in every case that I've used it), just going to need a bit more info.